# Building local Teams chat with polling on mgt Get Component- polling and throttling

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am building local teams chat integrated with a product using Microsoft graph API toolkit. I am using mgt react Get Component to pull the messages from the channel . I am using polling rate as 3 seconds as I want to pull the messages from teams near real time .

I am also using cache for 24 hours invalidation period for the Get component

By any chance this will lead to throttling issues or graph API toolkit manages this internally?

Attached is the screenshot.
screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqaZ9.jpg)

Comment: I dont remember something documented in the above lines. But throttling limits vary based on the scenario. For example, if you are performing a large volume of writes, the possibility for throttling is higher than if you are only performing reads.. So if you're getting throttled then you will get HTTP 429(Too many requests). Do you receive it?

Comment: Hi Dev , I haven't released this on production as yet. But just wanted to be sure that this should not cause throttling. Mostly my operations are read with polling, and frequency of write is less and on demand only.

Comment: Hi @Dev , I have started getting 429 now as I released to few users. Don't understand why polling is made available with value determined in milliseconds when the thereshold limits of graph API especially with Teams is so less... Do you suggest any other option to get the latest messages from specific conversation inside a channel and update the client ... As I need a chatty behaviour so the updates has to be near real time ... Kind of stuck here